# SAS Array subscript out of range

Tags: sas

I am getting the Array subscript out of range error:

```
ERROR: Array subscript out of range at line 408 column 169.
SYM_ROOT=FSV DATE=. TIME_M=. BID=. BIDSIZ=. ASK=. ASKSIZ=. EXN=.
FIRST.SYM_ROOT=1 LAST.SYM_ROOT=1 FIRST.DATE=1 LAST.DATE=1 FIRST.TIME_M=1
LAST.TIME_M=1 nexb1=. nexb2=. nexb3=. nexb4=. nexb5=. nexb6=. nexb7=. nexb8=.
nexb9=. nexb10=. nexb11=. nexb12=. nexb13=. nexb14=. nexb15=. nexb16=. nexb17=.
nexo1=. nexo2=. nexo3=. nexo4=. nexo5=. nexo6=. nexo7=. nexo8=. nexo9=. nexo10=.
nexo11=. nexo12=. nexo13=. nexo14=. nexo15=. nexo16=. nexo17=. sexb1=. sexb2=.
sexb3=. sexb4=. sexb5=. sexb6=. sexb7=. sexb8=. sexb9=. sexb10=. sexb11=.
sexb12=. sexb13=. sexb14=. sexb15=. sexb16=. sexb17=. sexo1=. sexo2=. sexo3=.
sexo4=. sexo5=. sexo6=. sexo7=. sexo8=. sexo9=. sexo10=. sexo11=. sexo12=.
sexo13=. sexo14=. sexo15=. sexo16=. sexo17=. _I_=. i=18 BB=. BO=. MIDPRICE=.
BBSize=. BOSize=. NUMEX=. _ERROR_=1 _N_=6417740
```

However, I am not sure what happened, because the code has previously worked on a different dataset.

The only thing that I can think of is that, because the dataset I am having problem with is the subset of the original one (which worked), it might not have the complete range of exn (I am using a variable named exn as the index of the array).

I defined the array as:

```
array nexb nexb:; array nexo nexo:; array sexb sexb:; array sexo sexo:;
```

The variable I am talking about is called exn, and it is used to reference the array:

```
nexb(exn)=bid;nexo(exn)=ofr;sexb(exn)=bidsiz;sexo(exn)=ofrsiz;
```

The arrays are initialized in the following way:

```
do i=1 to 17;
  nexb(i)=.; nexo(i)=.; sexb(i)=.; sexo(i)=.;
end;
```

Originally exn spans from 1 to 17. Now I think some of the numbers in between might be missing in the dataset. But why is that a problem? They are initialized anyways.

Comment: If you're using EXN as the index I would have assumed it would be in the error message as well. It's not. You should post the line of code that's referred to in the log as well, Line 408 - it tells you exactly where it's having issues with the index.

Comment: I don't even have line 408 in my code ...

Comment: It's running on a cluster I guess that's why

Comment: yes you do, look at your log, it has line numbers. READ YOUR LOG.

Comment: You need to post the log. The log has the line numbers, not the code.

Comment: I used Macros. The log has only the line number for the macro.

Comment: exn is missing on that record line, so if you were trying to use it that's likely why it's causing an error.

Comment: Actually that might be the reason. Let me re-run it with `if exn ne .;` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a missing value as the index into an array.  Your log shows that EXN is missing.